# SAS: when using PROC TRANSREG, ODS does not generate boxcox

Tags: macros, sas, distribution

Hi I am using proc transreg in a SAS Macro.

The code listed as follows,

```
  %if &cnt_amt>0 %then %do;
    ods output boxcox=boxcox; 

    proc transreg data=data0; 
      where &response>0;
      model BoxCox(&response / lambda=0.05 to 1 by 0.05) = identity(&vars_amt);
      run;

    data _null_;
      set boxcox;
      if ci='<';
      call symput ('lambda',lambda);
      run;

  %end; /* %if cnt_amt>0 ... */
  %else %let lambda=0.4;
```

When I run the code on my work computer, the code run perfectly fine and does not give me any error message. However, when I run the code on my personal laptop, the code gives me an error message and the dataset work.boxcox is not generated.

I have been spending two weeks on this issue. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Following up,

**Here is the log when the code is running perfectly on my work computer,the dataset boxcox is generated**

```
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ods exclude all ;
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ;
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ** ods exclude all ;
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ods exclude all ;
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ;
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ** ods exclude all ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable TITLES resolves to 4
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   title5 "Starting Estimates for Amount Model" ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable LAMBDA resolves to
MLOGIC(MIXTRAN):  %IF condition &lambda eq  is TRUE
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable CNT_AMT resolves to 2
MLOGIC(MIXTRAN):  %IF condition &cnt_amt>0 is TRUE
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ods output boxcox=boxcox;
NOTE: There were 872 observations read from the data set WORK._PERSONS.
NOTE: The data set WORK._PERSONS has 872 observations and 8 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
  real time           0.04 seconds
  cpu time            0.03 seconds


MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   proc transreg data=data0;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESPONSE resolves to totaldfe
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   where totaldfe>0;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESPONSE resolves to totaldfe
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable VARS_AMT resolves to WEEKEND SEQORDER
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   model BoxCox(totaldfe / lambda=0.05 to 1 by 0.05) =     identity(WEEKEND
SEQORDER);
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   run;

**NOTE: The data set WORK.BOXCOX has 20 observations and 7 variables.**
NOTE: There were 936 observations read from the data set WORK.DATA0.
  WHERE totaldfe>0;
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSREG used (Total process time):
  real time           0.08 seconds
  cpu time            0.04 seconds
```

**Here is the log when the code is not running well on my laptop. The dataset boxcox is not generated**

```
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ** ods exclude all ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable TITLES resolves to 4
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   title5 "Starting Estimates for Amount Model" ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable LAMBDA resolves to
MLOGIC(MIXTRAN):  %IF condition &lambda eq  is TRUE
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable CNT_AMT resolves to 2
MLOGIC(MIXTRAN):  %IF condition &cnt_amt>0 is TRUE
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   ods output boxcox=boxcox;
NOTE: There were 872 observations read from the data set WORK._PERSONS.
NOTE: The data set WORK._PERSONS has 872 observations and 8 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE SORT used (Total process time):
  real time           0.03 seconds
  cpu time            0.03 seconds


MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   proc transreg data=data0;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESPONSE resolves to totaldfe
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   where totaldfe>0;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable RESPONSE resolves to totaldfe
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable VARS_AMT resolves to WEEKEND SEQORDER
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   model BoxCox(totaldfe / lambda=0.05 to 1 by 0.05) =     identity(WEEKEND SEQORDER);
MPRINT(MIXTRAN):   run;

NOTE: There were 936 observations read from the data set WORK.DATA0.
  WHERE totaldfe>0;
NOTE: PROCEDURE TRANSREG used (Total process time):
  real time           0.10 seconds
  cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

** The dataset boxcox is not generated **

Thank you!

Comment: If the code runs fine on one computer it's probably an environment issue. You need to provide operating systems (windows/linux), SAS versions, etc. Also the error message is important.

Comment: Thanks to @DomPazz for your help! I added my log. On work computer, the dataset boxcox is generated; on my personal computer, the dataset boxcox is not generated.  Thank you!

Comment: That's weird.  Are you running the same version of SAS on both machines?  When you run on your machine, do you get printed output that includes the BoxCox output?

Comment: @DomPazz Yes. I run the same version of SAS (SAS 9.4). Is that something like I did not set up my directory/registry correct?

Comment: It is probably an ODS setting.  Do you see the BoxCox output in the listing or HTML on both machines?  This is a good question for SAS Tech Support.  http://support.sas.com  Give them a call and they can walk through this with you.

Comment: @DomPazz Yes! Finally I solved the problem by changing ODS setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens due to ODS setting. 
proc transreg can generate both plot and data. Because I want to save the data generated by **proc transreg**, I must turn the ODS graphics off.

Using one line 
    ods graphics off; 
before the macro (or changing the setting of ODS registry).

The problem is gone.

Thanks everyone for replying.